# ROUTES MARKING JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a code javascript with JSON .. The code it's ok .
The code draw the markers corectly, now I need link the points..
This is my code :

```
function initialize() {
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);

  var la;
  var lo;

  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.555, -76.29),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    var pathCoordinates = new google.maps.MVCArray();

    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
      for (var obj in data) {

        la = data[obj].a;
        lo = data[obj].o;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo),
          map: map
        });



      }
    }
  }
}

hr.send(null);
```

I use the next code for link of the marker but I can't save the JSON into array.

```
var marcadores = [{
  lat: 3.54849,
  lng: -76.2887
}, {
  lat: 3.54856,
  lng: -76.3000
}];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: marcadores,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: 'green',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem...

the solution was this :

```
                arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng( la , lo));
                     }                  

                        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: arr,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: 'green',
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                            });

                        flightPath.setMap(map);
```